# Very broad answers as redirect point is good to Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

To start, I'm talking specifically about Stack Overflow, since I don't use much of the other Stack Exchange environments.

A common practice is to create a very broad Q&A about some topic (example: What's a compiler and how to use it). Then, every new question about it, even when it's only part of the problem, is almost promptly closed or marked as duplicate, with link to that one.

Is this really a good way for sites like Stack Overflow? As a community, naturally should be a place for discussion, I can't see how a very broad manual engulfing every single problem, with their own features, will help. Though I understand there is a serious issue with REALLY duplicate questions, many of them are being dropped on a "hub" topic, that helps too little (or too much, sometimes).

Being more clear, my own example. I've just published this question
[Unresolved external symbols in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097257/unresolved-external-symbols-in-vs2013) and in a minute or two, another user marked as duplicate of the "hub" one, this [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

I had read it, but it's a true technical guide! My question is a personal problem, so if all of such will be redirect to a broad guide, I really don't see much point on a community: let's just publish a guide website. No personal problems, no discussion. Or as I said there, maybe I'm seeing Stack Overflow in a very wrong way.

That's my point, sorry about my English, and thank you all.

Comment: If you're really only interested in this as it relates to SO, don't you think it makes sense for this to be on *their* Meta site, rather than on MSE?

Comment: "naturally should be a place for discussion," StackExchange websites are a horrible medium for a discussion,  since Stackoverflow, is not a discussion forum

Comment: Catija, same seems to happen on WordPress StackExchange (less frequent), that's why I choose to talk specifically about SO, not discarding the possibility of the same being happen on other SE places.

Comment: Definitely you got me wrong with (or I mischoose) the "discussion" word. My point is: all questions are becoming irrelevant in favor of the "great guides" answers, that most of the time, don't apply to all situations and don't apply as answer to specific questions, they are too broad.

Comment: I recommend revising your advocacy of discussion out of your question before that starts to attract downvotes here or at Meta [so].

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why my "advocacy of discussion" can attract downvotes?

Comment: The focussed Q&A format of SE sites is the antithesis of discussion but you seem to be saying that SO "should be a place for discussion".  See the third dot point in the answer that you have accepted.

Comment: Nothing else to say, feel free to close/delete it.

Comment: Questions that seek out discussions...and votes on meta mean we don't agree with your suggestion and/or feature request

Comment: No problem, programmers.stack seems like a better option anyway. As I said "maybe I'm seeing Stack Overflow in a very wrong way."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- The duplicate target is an older question (from 2012), back when broader questions were seemingly allowed. Things have changed, particularly with the expectations of question quality (especially with regards to how broad questions can be). It may have been common in the past, but it is generally not allowed now.
- Stack Overflow is not a help desk, so you'll need to word your question in a way that has a uniqueness about it. Something specific that would also serve to benefit anyone else coming along and reading it (and any answers). I have found that searching specific topics yields many results.
- Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum - this is by design. The aim is to build a repository of knowledge on the Internet. Questions are to be answered, not discussed.

I find that breaking down the problem and searching for specific topics yields much more focused and useful entries.

A bit of a personal experience related to this - lately, I have been working on an Android based project, one that has many facets - and have found by searching specific parts of my requirements, I have managed to complete the project without having to ask a single question (and was able to answer a question in the process).

*(as a small token of appreciation for the helpful questions and answers, I have upvoted them as I read and used the information).*

Comment: By "discussion" I'm targeting the question, not "chit-chat" or off-topic, sure. At the same time, SO description says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." Much of closed questions seems like this to me, but a broad Q&A is pointed as an "all situation solution".

Comment: That's why I break down the problems, and search for very specific topics.

Comment: Sure, I do this most of the time, upvoting an answer when it helps me. But how can we choose "very specific topics" if most of them are being cut in favor of broad answers? It's like a (in my view, negative) bottleneck.